# Counterexample to inverse Leibniz alternating series test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

The alternating series test is a sufficient condition for the convergence of a numerical series. I am searching for a counterexample for its inverse: i.e. a series (alternating, of course) which converges, but for which the hypothesis of the theorem are false.

In particular, if one writes the series as $\sum (-1)^n a_n$, then $a_n$ should not be monotonically decreasing (since it must be infinitesimal, for the series to converge).

Comment: Interlace the terms $1/n^2$ and $1/n^3$ (with appropriate signs).

Comment: did you mean to say that the absolute values of the general terms should not be monotinically decreasing (since if the series has alternating signs, surely the general terms can't be monotone). And you should really change the title. There are no counterexamples to Leibnitz's test!

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of $\sum (-1)^n a_n$, where $a_n\ge0$.

Comment: Do you want to stipulate that the series is still *conditionally* convergent?

Comment: Yes (are you thinking of something else?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put:
$$
b_n = \begin{cases}
n^{-2} &: n \text{ odd} \\
2^{-n} &: n \text{ even} 
\end{cases}
$$

$b_n$ is not monotonically decreasing. Still, $\sum (-1)^n b_n$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a conditionally convergent series in which the signs alternate, but we do not have monotonicity, look at 
$$\frac{1}{2}-1+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{8}-\frac{1}{7}+\cdots.$$
It is not hard to show that this converges to the same number as its more familiar sister.